# How to query Non Unique Together values in Django or SQL?

Tags: python, sql, django, postgresql

Let's say I have this model:

```
class Contact(BaseModel):
    order = models.ForeignKey(Order, related_name='contacts', blank=True, null=True)
    type = models.CharField(max_length=15, choices=TYPES, blank=True))
```

I want to find all orders where `order` and `type` are not unique together.

For example, there is `order A` and there are related contacts:

```
Contact(order=orderA, type='broker')
Contact(order=orderA, type='broker')
Contact(order=orderA, type='delivery')
```

I want to find this `orderA` because this order and `type='broker'` are not unique together in `Contact` model.

And then there is `orderB` and these related contacts:

```
Contact(order=orderB, type='broker')
Contact(order=orderB, type='delivery')
```

I don't want this `orderB` because it and the field `type` are unique in `Contact` model.

I tried using `annonate()` of Django but failed to relate these two fields.

Is it possible to do this with Django queries?

If not, a slight hint of how I could do it in SQL would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use a SQL query like:

```
select distinct order_id
from (
    select order_id, type
    from Contact
    group by order_id, type
    having count(*) > 1);
```

The "order" column is shown as "order_id" because that's the way Django names columns.

Comment: `order` should be `order_id`, and you should add an alias to the subquery, but otherwise this should work.

Comment: @rd_nielsen thank you. If you make corrections suggested by Назар, I will accept it. Thank you both of you.

Answer (score 3):

This should do the trick

```
qs = (Contact.objects.values('order','type')
         .annotate(cnt=models.Count('pk'))
         .filter(cnt__gt=1))
```

Answer (score 1):

You could write a couple methods to solve this problem. I might have gone over board writing these methods for you but regardless heres an explaination.
`def equal_to` takes self and some other contact, returns true if that contact is the same order and type else false. `def all_not_unique` returns a list of all not unique contact objects with no duplicates. And should be called like, `not_unique = Contact.all_not_unique()`.

```
def equal_to(self, other):
    assert(self.id != other.id)
    if self.order.id == other.order.id:
        if self.type == other.type:
            return True
    return false

@classmethod
def all_not_unique(cls):
    query_set = cls.objects.all()
    not_unique_query_set = []
    for contact_one in query_set:
        found = False
        for contact_two in query_set:
            if not found:
                if contact_one.id != contact_two.id:
                    if contact_one.equal_to(contact_two):
                        not_unique_query_set.append(contact_one)
                        found = True
```